# using maven-war-plugin with Spring BOM

Tags: spring, maven, maven-war-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

I'm trying to add Spring BOM to my project. My POM is below.

1. Am I not doing something correctly here?
2. Also, a semi-related question: why do the version numbers for spring-ws, spring-data-jpa, and others not line up with the version of spring core, context, etc?

   ```
   <build>
       <finalName>myproject</finalName>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <version>3.1</version>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.7</source>
                   <target>1.7</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>

   <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
               <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
               <type>pom</type>
               <scope>import</scope>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
               <exclusions>
                   <exclusion>
                       <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                       <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                   </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
           </dependency>
       ...
       </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

   <dependencies>

       <!-- Spring -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
           <version>${spring-ws.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
           <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
       </dependency>
   ...
   </dependencies>
   ```

It produces the following error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.863s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri May 09 13:15:24 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/214M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on
project myproject: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin
:2.1.1:war failed: For artifact {org.springframework:spring-core:null:jar}: The version cannot be em
pty. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plug
ins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on project myproject: Execution default-war o
f goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war failed: For artifact {org.springframework
:spring-core:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-BOM Spring dependencies go in the `dependencies` section, not `dependencyManagement`.

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-ws.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: this was the ticket. care to answer my 2nd question for best answer?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of how or why the Spring team versions things as they do. My guess is that they consider them separate suites.  Notice that the group IDs are different.  Maybe the Spring team has their versioning policies on their main website somewhere?